# How can I check the firmware version of a primesense Xtion camera?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, firmware, asus-xtion, primesense

How can I check the firmware version of a primesense Xtion camera?

I have a couple of these cameras which I suspect have different firmware versions. One works with NiViewer, the other doesn't. Although both are detected as connected to a usb port (I repeat the test on the same usb port). I don't want to flash firmware upgrades directly without knowing the current versions (I recently screwup another camera by just trying different firmwares). Ideally, I'm looking for some app I could run from ubuntu that can show the firmware version of the camera.

Looking at APIs, I found a getFirmwareRevision() call for the [Structure SDK](https://structure.io/developers) but I think that's for the occipital camera only. I've checked [OpeneNI2](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2) API and the most similar sounding function I've found is a call to GetFirmwareParams() but I can't see any example that refers to the firmware version, so I suspect that's for a different use.

Comment: I'm confused - is this a programming question?

Comment: I thought there maybe some API call to retrieve the version. I can only see code using OpenNI and I can't see any calls to check the firmware version in OpenNI